# is it possible to disable mouse visual mode in vim?

Tags: vim

I have a problem that when I use my mouse to focus on my vim window, I often end up in Visual mode. However, I like many of the mouse functions such as resizing windows and selecting tabs.

Is there any way to leave mouse mode enabled, but disable the mouse's ability to enter Visual mode when accidentally selecting text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your $HOME/.vimrc configuration.

```
set mouse=nicr
```

Or if you want to use on the fly in vim , try with command mode `:set mouse=nicr`

For some user's `set mouse-=a` also works, but that is not working for me.

Comment: This disables the ability to copy with mouse...